# current url as a input value jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

I have an input field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="url" id="url">
```

I want this input in form load to have as value the current url, I did it with jquery and it works.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#url').val(window.location);
});
```

But how can I simplify it without jquery, since with `window.location` we can get current URL value, can I do something like this even that this doesn't work:

```
<input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value=window.location>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot put JS code in the `value` attribute, and `input` elements have no `onload` attribute you could use (not that that would be very good practice anyway). A pure JS alternative would be to put a `<script>` tag just before the `</body>` containing just this:

```
document.getElementById('url').value = window.location;
```

All that being said, if you are using jQuery in your site anyway I see no reason not to keep using your original solution within the document.ready event handler.